# ASP.NET MVC3, tyring to migrate from SQL Server CE to Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have an MVC3 project that I've been developing up until this point using SQL Compact Edition.  I now am trying to move over to SQL Server 2008 R2 running on a different machine.  I have connected to this database with Visual Studio and obtained a connection string which I have used to replace my existing connection string.

```
<add name="CPContext" connectionString="Data Source=CSP111;Initial Catalog=CONTESTPLATFORM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<%MY PASSWORD%>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<!--Old Connection String
<add name="CPContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|ContestPlatform.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
-->
```

I am using an initializer class to seed the database with some initial values.  This is called in my Global.asax.cs file like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CPContext>(new ContestPlatformInitializer());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Now when I go to run my project, an exception is thrown when the first attempt is made to access the database.

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model
metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code 
First or Code First Migrations.
```

This is the code on my home page that is throwing the exception:

```
IQueryable<Submission> submissions = db.Submissions.Where(s => s.ContestId == contestId && s.Entry.isPrivate != true && s.Entry.isApproved);
```

When I go to my database, no tables have been created.  New to entity framework, help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the new database is not yet "populated", in that neither the database objects (e.g., tables, views) nor their data is present.

I'm not familiar with SQL CE, but what you need to do is migrate your database from CE to the new server. I do that fairly frequently when I move a project from a development environment to a production environment, because the database server is different for each environment.

Read up on how to copy a CE database to a Sql Server database. You can probably create a project in Sql Server Business Development Studio to do it.

Comment: There isn't any data that needs to be kept from the CE database.  I figured that if the tables didn't exist, EF would generate them based on the models like it had been doing for CE.  With CE, I frequently would delete my database to 'start fresh' and EF would recreate it automatically.